# How to provide a file name through scanf for cvloadimage in opencv

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I have a batch of images to process. Every time I want to use a differnt image I have to go the code and change the name of the source image. I want to know, instead of that can I use a printf and scanf_s to type in the required filename.
here's the code that I tried:-

```
    char filename[20];
    printf("Enter the filename\n");
    scanf_s("%c",&filename);
    src = cvLoadImage(filename);
```

if I want to load an image in the name 123.png,how do I do it? Also, the images I want are in a folder named "source". Normally

```
cvloadImage("source\\123.png",3)
```

would suffice,but  how to do it in my case? Also I want to save the image in an another folder "saved". I know how to use cvSaveImage in the conventional way,but here I want enter the name for the save file just like I did with the source file. Any Ideas?

Update:- Got the answer, Thank You guys :)

Comment: Not very sure, but from Pure C perspective, `scanf_s("%c",&filename);` --> `scanf_s("%s",filename);` should suffice.

Comment: I tried that but cvLoadImage only accepts *char.

Comment: @SouravGhosh One more argument of size has to be passed with that .

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! That looks like a pure C question, so do not add C++ tag. If you use a C++ compiler, **change** to C++ tag.

Comment: after reading the string you should print it to check the value of the variable. Probably you'll see the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you enter "123.png" as the input.

```
char filename[20];
char full_filename[30] = "source\\";
printf("Enter the filename\n");
scanf_s("%s",&filename);
strcat(full_filename, filename);
```

If you want to enter only "123" as the input.. add the following.

```
strcat(full_filename, ".png");
```

Finally.

```
src = cvLoadImage(full_filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't take input character by character . Take input as a string-

```
 scanf_s("%s",filename,_countof(filename));
```

3rd argument of size because `scanf_s` requires size as third argument with specifiers [`%c ,%s, %[`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).